# C code to extract pairing code from wiimote, strange result

Tags: c, bluetooth, driver, ubuntu-14.04, wiimote

I was helping someone over at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705865/how-to-pair-wiimote-in-ubuntu-15-10/705887?noredirect=1#comment1039256_705887) with , what should of been a simple issue of connecting a Wiimote to Ubuntu, however we ran in to a bug in the driver.

The driver would request a bluetooth `pairing code` for the device, the user did not have one.

The user found a post on [wiibrew](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote#Bluetooth_Pairing) explaining how to extract the code with a bit of C code.

They gave

```
char pin[6];
pin[0] = 0x6D;
pin[1] = 0x7E;
pin[2] = 0x3B;
pin[3] = 0x35;
pin[4] = 0x1E;
pin[5] = 0x00;
```

So. the user made what they thought was a valid C file

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) 

{
 char pin[6]; 
 pin[0] = 0x41; 
 pin[1] = 0x7D; 
 pin[2] = 0x5D;  
 pin[3] = 0x8A;
 pin[4] = 0xD2;
 pin[5] = 0x40; 

 printf("the password is:\n"); printf("%s \n", pin ); 

}
```

The code compiles fine, no errors, however it should produce a 6 number passcode but just displays what looks like nonsense characters,

```
 A}]��@
```

As I am not a programmer, I don't understand what is wrong with this output, why did it give this result and how can we get the actual pairing code using this ?

Comment: I think the above program hardcodes the *pairing code*. It has to be extracted from somewhere.

Comment: The code might be undefined behavior because something which is not a null-terminated string is passed to `%s`.

Comment: These are the correct characters you are printing. See: http://www.asciitable.com/ for the conversion between them. `A`, `}`, `]` and `@` are correct but `0x8A` and `0xD2` are not valid hexidecimal characters (hence the question marks). I think this code snippet was designed to be used another way and not just printed out (maybe by *pairing* these with something else??)

Comment: Thanks all for the responses, I guess we are barking up the wrong tree here, thanks for your time.

Comment: This is not the 6 digit PIN that's manually entered. This is the HCI PIN which, as your link explains, is a "binary bluetooth address", and won't be human readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is printing fine `0x8A` and `0xD2` are not valid ASCII characters. Ascii uses Hex values 0x00-0x7F.

[See here](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: If you want to print out the value in hex, you can do `printf("%X")` to print out the actual hex values. The pin is your WiiMote's MAC address backwards (as the guide stated), so hard coding should be fine. I do not think your code needs to actually compile based on what you posted, this is more a visual demonstration from what I gather.